# I need to delete apps that I have previously purchased and deleted from my account history

Tags: ios-appstore

I need to remove some apps from my account history forever because I don't want them anymore, and because iCloud keeps a new history format I need to know the process which is doing this.

Comment: Either not enough people have made this clear in http://apple.com/feedback or it could be something that gets added later. It certainly is in apples interest to never have use regret any purchase. We won't be as free trying things if we can't change our minds later and at least filter out the duds from that list.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you can. Your account history is on Apple's servers, so you can only read it. I doubt they'd delete anything from there for you just in case you change your mind and want it back. There's certainly nothing on your computer or iOS device that you can tweak to change your history.

Answer (score 2):

Apple now allows you to Hide purchases using iTunes 10.5.  Open iTunes Store > Purchases and then look for the purchases you want to Hide and click the X.

Beware it keeps a list of Hidden Purchases you can still view to get them back.

Answer (score 0):

While this does not remove the apps from your account entirely, you can remove them from the history list by viewing the Purchased items in App Store>Updates>Purchased and swiping left on the app you want to remove from the history list.